# How to change the RGB values of selected vertex in meshlab?

Tags: meshlab

I have loaded a textured pointcloud and I would like to put seeds (or call it labels ) of different colors (red, green) in the pointcloud. How to do this is meshlab? I know that in meshlab I can select vertex clusters, but how to assign a color value those selected points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each vertex has a parameter vsel that is equal to 1 if the vertex is selected, so you can use the filter "Per vertex Color Function" and write and expression that uses vsel, for example:

```
r = 255 
g = 255 * vsel
b = 255 * vsel
```

Comment: I am getting this error  **unexcpected token vsel found at func2 and func3**. Here is what I did. 1. Load the point cloud and select a part of it using _Select Vertex Colors_ . 2. Go to _Filters_ tab and select _Per Vertex Color Function_ 3. Define the color fucntion as in your answer and I get error mentioned.

Comment: It is working in version 2016-12 of meshlab. It seems that you are using version 1.3.3 or previous of meshlab.